# What's the difference in behavior between ifx and ifthenelse?

Tags: conditionals

Why does the `\ifx` test give a different answer than `\ifthenelse` in the following simple example?

testclass.cls (without the head and tail):

```
\newcommand{\isempty}{\@empty}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\isempty}{\@empty}}
   {\newcommand{\foo}{ifthen says yes}}
   {\newcommand{\foo}{ifthen says no}}
\ifx\isempty\@empty
   \newcommand{\foofoo}{ifx says yes}
   \else\newcommand{\foofoo}{ifx says no}
\fi
```

Now if I call commands `\foo` and `\foofoo` in a .tex file, I'll get the following output:

ifthen says yes

ifx says no

Why? Where's the difference? I thought that the following two would be equivalent:

```
\ifx\macroA\macroB\DoSomething\else\DoSomethingElse\fi
\ifthenelse{\equal{\macroA}{\macroB}}{\DoSomething}{\DoSomethingElse}
```

Are there some expansion problems?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, after

```
\newcommand{\isempty}{\@empty}
```

the test

```
\ifx\isempty\@empty
```

will return false, because

1. both `\isempty` and `\@empty` are macros, but
2. they differ in their `\long` status.

However, also `\newcommand*{\isempty}{\@empty}` would make the test fail, because

1. both `\isempty` and `\@empty` are macros, with the same `\long` status (both aren't `\long`), but
2. they differ in their first level expansion, which is `\@empty` for `\isempty` and nothing for `\@empty`.

This assumes, of course, that your code is preceded by `\makeatletter`.

Why does `\ifthenelse{\equal{\isempty}{\@empty}` follow the true branch? Because the test does *full* expansion of the arguments of `\equal`. In both arguments the full expansion is empty. From the package documentation:

> The ⟨*string*⟩s tested by `\equal` may be any sequence of commands that expand to a list of tokens. If these expansions are equal, then the proposition is true.

Basically, `\ifx` tests if the two tokens following it would give the same result when `\meaning` is applied to them. In the case of

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\isempty}{\@empty}
```

doing `\meaning\isempty` would print

> `\long macro:->\@empty`

while `\meaning\@empty` would print

> `macro:->`

so you see they're different as far as `\ifx` is concerned.

---

If you don't have `\makeatletter` before your code, the situation is a bit more complicated:

1. the full expansion of `\@empty`, which is six tokens long, is

   ```
   \spacefactor \@m empty
   ```
2. since `\isempty` first expands to `\@empty`, the `\ifthenelse` test will follow the true branch anyway;
3. The `\ifx` test will compare `\isempty` with `\@`, which returns false, so `empty` will disappear along with the true text and the false branch will be followed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Many thanks! Is there any way to make such a test go "yes" using `\ifx`?

Comment: @Mike `\let\isempty\@empty`